# Dude, Where's My Horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, my faithful steeds have had a history of, well, *draconic* incidents recently, and so, when leaving Solace, to head out in search of the Steed Stone recently, it occurred to me that procuring a new Equine conveyance would be wise.

The fine stableman over at The Solitude Stables, near Katla's farm, a trustworthy seeming fellow named Geimund, informed me that [his horse was amazing](http://www.weebls-stuff.com/songs/Amazing+Horse/), and availiable for a mere 1000 Septims.

I agreed to his price, and 1000 Septims poorer, was informed that it was 'the one with the Saddle'.

However, the horse with a saddle in this stable does not seem to be interested in turning into a plane or tasting like raisins, or showing me the universe. Hell, this horse isn't even interested in being ridden by me - at least, not if I don't want to be branded an inveterate and unpardonable *Horse-Thief* by every guard from Solituide to Markarth.

Why don't I own the Horse with the Saddle now? Is there a different horse with a saddle that I paid for? Did it wander off? There are only two stalls at the stable, both are occupied by horses, only one has a saddle, and the ride option for both are in red.

I just want a new pony. :(

Comment: You need more carrots.

Comment: For anyone who lands here because they *lost* their horse, see: [How can I find or recall my horse?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40933/how-can-i-find-or-recall-my-horse)

Comment: thats why i'm sparing Astrid when she kidnapped me. Shadowmere is a beast :D

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like a bug. Pickpocket him to get your money back and try again.

Comment: He won't sell me another horse. He says he's all out.

Comment: +1 for getting the money back, it allows you to buy a horse at a different stable.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug, and doesn't seem to go away with save reloading or game restarting. However, you may not own the horse at his stables, but if you fast travel somewhere, your mount may show up. It may only show up if you fast travel to a different stable.

Answer (score 5):

Let your body wander to a different location and your steed might find you. (try fast travel)

Comment: Been there, tried that. :(

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reloading a previous save and trying again, I've found that it somtimes fixes bugs similar to this.
If this does not work, reload once again and buy another horse from a different city.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, rather than remaining motionless at the stable, the horse has a wander path with a fair radius.

For example upon fast to Markarth, my horse spawns near the stable, but immediately starts wandering down the road. I followed him to see how far he sent, and he stopped halfway out on the second bridge on the road from Markarth, a fair distance from the city gates. When I finished my business in town, he was nowhere within eyeshot. Only two non-owned horses in the stable. But sure enough, head to the bridge down the road, and the horse is there.

The horse may have similar paths near other towns and stables.