# Is there a way to call your horse in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find or recall my horse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40933/how-can-i-find-or-recall-my-horse)

I am contemplating buying a horse, but for the price of 1K I want to know if I can at least call it to me once I have it.

Comment: Have you tried "Here horsey, horsey, horsey."?

Comment: What do you mean by call? You mean to do something to get your horse to appear to help you ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you fast travel to any location, your horse should appear next to you.
If it stops appearing check the stables where you bought it from.

Answer (score 2):

By default no. There is no call for the horse.  Although, there are nice mods out there for that ability.

Check [here for that mod.](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=3251)