# Where is my horse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

During an epic multiplayer horse adventure we stopped in a desert and had a run-in with monsters, panic, and general chaos. In the morning, we had lost a horse in the jungle across the river from the desert, and combing the place didn't turn up any sign of it.

We were fond of that horse, and would like to rescue it. It definitely didn't get killed by monsters, as it was dismounted far from the site of battle and horses aren't targeted by mobs unless there is a player on it. We just can't *find* it.

How can we locate our horse?

This is a heavily modded Forge-based MC 1.6.2 server, so mod solutions are welcome. (I can't use Bukkit plugins right now, but those are welcome too as I may be adding Bukkit support later, and the horse is likely in an unloaded chunk and not going anywhere anytime soon.) Note that I've seen the [Where is my horse? + Horsebook](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1912164-162sspwhere-is-my-horse-horsebook/) mod, but it doesn't help *after* you've lost your horse.

Comment: Dude, where's my horse?  Sorry, I just had to.

Comment: @MBraedley I was very tempted to make that the title. Maybe I should.

Comment: @MBraedley Hah, I can't: ["error: that title already exists"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38858/dude-wheres-my-horse).

Comment: Stupid database unique keys

Comment: Have you checked between your legs?

Comment: @Batphobia That's my *other* horse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The horse definitely wasn't killed by monsters, but it died nonetheless.

Using [NBT Explorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) I opened the world save, navigated to the region NBT branch, and ran a search for the horse's owner's name. Since horse entities are stored inside the chunk data inside regions and have an `OwnerName` NBT entry that contains the name of the player who tamed them, after a while this gave me a complete list of all living horses tamed by that player. The horse in question ("Giblet") was not among them.

The horse probably drowned under a jungle bush's leaf block while having a swim, or fell off a cliff. Now we know!

Had the horse been alive, this method of digging through the region data with an NBT editor/reader would have worked quite well (and did, for all our living horses). With access to the save files, this is the most direct and non-invasive way to locate a horse lost under a wide variety of circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

## [Horse Locator Mod](http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/161162-horse-locator-v01-compatible-with-smp-forge-compatible/)

You can use the horse locator mod. It shows you the coordinates (and the relative distance) of the nearest horse to your current position.

[image: Example Screenshot]

It is compatible with Forge and SMP. I used the mod in 1.6.1 but it should work in 1.6.2 as well.

Answer (score -3):

You might want to look for the closest village. Every time I lose a horse, I find it in the closest village.

Answer (score -4):

When you run in with monsters and you get off your horse then your horse probably got so scared when you died it ran away. Or it could have been killed by the mobs.

Comment: Nobody died, mobs don't attack unattended horses (source: extensive experience), and horses ain't scared of *nothing*. Horseybager don't give a damn.